# How to get different random numbers in array?

Tags: ruby, random

I have this code -

```
number1, number2, number3, number4, number5 = Array.new(5) { rand(99999)+1 }
```

How can I make sure that each number is unique?
Also - is it possible to output all numbers as 5 digit? Like 00147 instead of 147?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list = []
(list << '%05i' % (rand(99999)+1)).uniq! while list.length < 5
number1, number2, number3, number4, number5 = list
```

Comment: You could eliminate `list` with `[].tap {|a| (a << '%05i' % (rand(99999)+1)).uniq! while a.length < 5}`.  I prefer the way you've done it, but thought it was worth a mention.

Comment: shouldn't it be while list.length <= 5, as it would not reach 5 elements in the list

Comment: @bjhaid, if you had run the code first you wouldn't be asking.  (I say this as someone who recently made an incorrect suggestion in a comment because I hadn't first checked the code. :-) ).

Comment: Can you tell me where is the trick why I cannot use the numbers for mathematical calculations? And what should I change for that? Like, add one for the number or divide by 2 etc.

Comment: @CarySwoveland gotcha, the list is appended before the clause is reached

Comment: @ReinholdsRRazums it is a string and not an integer

Comment: @ReinholdsRRazums Use `number1.to_i` to use it in calculations.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I like the `tap` idea, thank you.

Comment: ...or a slight variant: `{}.tap {|h| h['%05i' % (rand(99999)+1)] = 'cat' while h.length < 5}.keys` (or `require 'set'`, `Set.new`...).

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_unique_random(n)
  a = []
  while n > 0 do
    r = "%05d" % (rand(99999)+1)
    (a << r; n -= 1) unless a.include?(r)
  end
  a
end

get_unique_random(5)
```

[Edit: I fixed an error I had introduced with an edit.  (Ever done that?)  Previously I had:

```
r = rand(99999)+1;
(a << "%05d" % r; n -= 1) unless a.include?(r)
```

I will leave it as an exercise to spot the error.]

Comment: Yeah, I tried with code like this previously... But how can I define the numbers to variables here? I need to insert them in different places later.

Comment: I don't understand, Reinholds.  `get_unique_random(5)` returns an array of five random numbers.

Comment: @Cary Sometimes it will return an array of four random numbers.

Comment: @steenslag, I see that, before I made the edit, the array returned may have contained duplicates, but I don't understand how it could have returned four random numbers, considering that `n` is decremented whenever an element is added to the array.  Perhaps I'm just a bit dense today.  Please explain.

Comment: I seem to be a bit dense today too, missed the that `-=1` is not executed in case of a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the simplest approach to me.  Each number is guaranteed to be unique.

```
array = (1...99999).to_a
unique_randoms = 5.times.map { '%05i' % array.delete_at(rand(array.length)) }
```

Comment: Changes are low, but you might get duplicates.

Comment: How can I define the numbers to variables here? I need to insert them in different places later.

Comment: @Vache I updated my answer.  Thoughts?

Comment: @ReinholdsRRazums the numbers are in an array called unique_randoms that got populated by the block.

Comment: Well it works but you generate a 99999 element array for nothing. :/ That's quite the overhead!

Comment: Josh, I think this is a case of "digging oneself in deeper", something we've all done at one time or another. (-:

Comment: `(1...99999).to_a.sample(5)`

Comment: @steenslag, `sample` is perfect!  (Well, maybe not perfect, because of the `to_a`, but that's minor.)  I suggest you convert your comment to an answer, so it will be more visible.